# Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring- beans-4.0.xsd'?

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

when I created my project on my own pc using eclipse March 2, I had no problem, but when I moved eclipse from my PC to the desktop I received a error message on my security-config.xml:

error msg:

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
- cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'security:http'.
- Start tag of element <security:http>
- schema_reference.4: Failed to read schema document 'http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-
 security.xsd', because 1) could not find the document; 2) the document could not be read; 3) the root element of the document is 
 not <xsd:schema>.
```

my security-config.xml file is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:form-login login-page="/app/main" default-target-url="/app/account" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/app/logout" logout-success-url="/app/main" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userServices">
            <security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userServices" />
        <property name="hideUserNotFoundExceptions" value="false" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationManager" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
        <constructor-arg>
            <ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

for more details on my laptop it work perfectly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/

You may just need to add the versionnumber of the spring security that you are using. Maybe your laptop has an old version cached and they removed the versionless one from their website.

this one should work:
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd